# How do I merge two LINQ statements into one to perform a list2.Except(list1)?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Currently, I have the following LINQ queries. How can I merge the two queries into one. Basically, write a LINQ query to bring back the results I'd get from

```
IEnumerable<int> deltaList = people2010.Except(allPeople);
```

except in a single query.

```
var people2010 = Contacts.Where(x => x.Contractors
.Any(d => d.ContractorsStatusTrackings
.Any(date => date.StatusDate.Year >= 2010)))
.Select(x => x.ContactID);

var allPeople = Contacts.Where(x => x.Contractors
.Any(m => m.ContactID == x.ContactID))
.Select(x=> x.ContactID);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Logically, does it makes sense to get a subset of people that excludes everybody? Then why do your variable names imply that's what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can you not just do `Except` as you are doing? Don't forget that your `people2010` and `allPeople` variables are just queries - they're not the data. Why not just use them as they are?

If that's not acceptable for some reason, please give us more information - such as whether this is in LINQ to Object, LINQ to SQL etc, and what's wrong with just using Except.

Comment: "Don't forget that your people2010 and allPeople variables are just queries - they're not the data" - Good point! At this point, there's to reason to avoid Except. I was looking for posible ways to improve the query. Perhaps writing one query instead of two.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're just looking for a more elegant way to write your query. I believe that this is a more elegant way to write your combined queries:

```
var deltaList =
    from contact in Contacts
    let contractors = contact.Contractors
    where contractors.Any(ctor => ctor.ContractorStatusTrackings
                                      .Any(date => date.StatusDate.Year >= 2010))
          && !contractors.Any(m => m.ContactID == contact.ContactID)
    select contact.ContactID
```